# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided user id was not a full JID (Smack)

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Использую Smack и xmpp для отправки сообщений в приложении, при попытке отправить картинку получаю ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided user id was not a full JID` в строчке:

```
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(id);
```

Перед этим узнаю id пользователя через:

```
String id= roster.getPresence("test2@irynas-macbook-air.local").getStanzaId();
```

Что не так? где взять `full JID`?

Comment: вместо `getStanzaId()` - `getFrom()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я поняла в чем проблема нужно было указывать `id` в таком формате: `test2@irynas-macbook-air.local/Irynas-MacBook-Air`, где Irynas-MacBook-Air - это `resource`.